# How to load ajax url where ajax calls using session to display result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im trying to create an edit function in my form using ajax. What i have right now in my ajax is like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "function/edit.php", 
dataType:"html", 
data:myData,
success:function(response){
   $("#record-center-content").load("function/edit.php");
},  
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  alert(thrownError);
}
});
```

Inside edit.php:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

    $idToEdit = $_POST["recordToEdit"]; 


    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ApplicationID FROM table1 WHERE ApplicationID = '".$idToEdit."'");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            $appid = $row['ApplicationID'];

        }

    $_SESSION['ApplicationID'] = $appid;

    var_dump($_SESSION['ApplicationID']);

?> ...... (html input form)
```

I dont know if that is a good idea, but my GOAL is after i clicked the edit button the edit form will be displayed which is inside edit.php and get the ID from session so i can use it. The problem is after the edit.php is loaded i get the NULL value which is supposed to be the ID from the database since i already stored it as a session. And when itry to do this in my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "function/edit.php", 
dataType:"html", 
data:myData,
success:function(response){

   returnValue = response;
   alert(returnValue);

},  
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
  alert(thrownError);
}
});
```

it shows the ID.

Comment: Why doesn't the AJAX call just return the HTML you want to display, instead of you having to make a second call to retrieve it?

Comment: @Barmar because the HTML form (tags) is inside the edit.php , am i getting your question correctly? if im going to create a different page where to display my form then i need to pass it again using ajax to the next form?

Comment: I don't understand your `while` loop. You're setting the same variable each time through the loop, so at the end `$appid` will just be the last row. You need to use an array to get all the rows.

Comment: You're alerting the ID because the script does `var_dump($_SESSION['ApplicationID'])`. Just display the HTML, and use `$("#record-center-content").html(response)` in the callback function.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar, you're right. I already get it. :)